# Why is my array formula not pulling in all indexed values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data: column A has letters, column E has jobs, and the rows for that job have certain letters. In C1, I want to put a formula down that index’s columns E:I and lets me know which jobs have 2 or more of those letters specified in column A.

[image: data set]

My formula works for job 3 because it contains (a,d,f) in that row, but also should include job 1. Any idea why it’s not pulling in jobs 1&3 in column C?

Formula: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$3,INDEX($F$1:$I$3,ROWS($E$1:E3),),0)),1,0))>=2,INDEX($E$1:$E$3,ROWS($E$1:E3)),"")`

Comment: Can you mock up the desired result? What do you want to see? `ROWS($E$1:E3)` will return `3`, so the INDEX only looks at F3:I3.

Comment: Also, you can use the Windows Snipping Tool to take a screenshot.

Comment: Oh so if I change that to ROWS($E$1:E1), press ctrl+shift+enter, and paste that to C2, it should work when I auto fill C2, right?

Comment: or potentially change ROWS to ROW depends on what you are trying to achieve with that part of the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula into cell C1 and confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$3,INDEX($F$1:$I$3,ROWS($E$1:E1),),0)),1,0))>=2,INDEX($E$1:$E$3,ROWS($E$1:E1)),"")
```

Then copy the formula down. You will then see `job1` in C1, C2 is blank and C3 has `job3`.

Comment: Is there a way to omit blanks? I can easily filter out, but just curious. Also, will try in the morning and respond back. Thank you!

Comment: This worked great, I can just copy & paste as values and filter out the blank spots. Thanks, again!